# How to create multiple details sections in Crystal Report?

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, report

I am new to crystal Report & in last few days I enjoyed few basic Reports. I must say it is dam good and look more professional tool.  Today I stuck up with one basic presentation issue, I was not able to present the data in clients desired format. Guys kindly help me out if you can do anything or you are good at Crystal Report

The following is the data presentation, where I think we need multiple section that can keep on repeating like in case of Group Section. I was able to show Person detail with eigther Education detail or with Experience detail, but how to show with both I have no idea. I have put the Person details in group header & rest that will be repeating put into detail section.

### Personal Details

```
Person Name
Address
Contact No.
EmailID
Date of birth
```

### Education Details

```
1   Education1      2010-11     75% Mumbai, India
2   Education2      2011-12     85% Mumbai, India
3   Education3      2012-13     65% Mumbai, India
4   Education4      2012-13     79% Mumbai, India
```

### Experience Details

```
1   Job1        Trainee             5mnth   Mumbai, India
2   Job2        Developer           9mnth   Mumbai, India
3   Job3        Project Manager     8mnth   Mumbai, India
4   Job4        CTO                 6mnth   Mumbai, India
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a subreport Vikash. Once you create one, you can set header and data for that and it should appear.